# Combinatorially equivalent polyhedra?

Tags: terminology, polyhedra, combinatorial-geometry

What does it mean for two polyhedra to be **combinatorially equivalent**? I've looked on the internet but in vain. If it's not a standard definition, then it might help to say that I found this term in a paper on flattening polyhedra: *Continuous flattening of convex polyhedra* by Jin-ichi Itoh et al.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The set of all faces of a polytope, partially ordered by inclusion, is called its face lattice. Two polytopes are combinatorially equivalent if they have isomorphic face lattices.

A nice introduction to the combinatorial aspects of polytopes can be found [in this pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bz4LnyhpU2BrjCN7CTR9I1YyxiPpav2A/view?usp=drivesdk).

An equivalent condition for combinatorial equivalence between two polytopes is that their face-vertex incidence matrices differ only by column and row permutations.

Comment: The link no longer works.

Comment: I have updated the link.

Answer (score 6):

For convex 3-dimensional polyhedra you can determine if two such polyhedra are combinatorially equivalent by looking at their vertex-edge graphs. It is known that a graph is the vertex-edge graph of a convex 3-dimensional polyhedron if and only if the graph is planar and 3-connected (Steinitz's Theorem). So if two convex 3-dimensional polyhedra have graphs which are isomorphic they are combinatorially equivalent. For higher dimensional convex polytopes you have to look at the face lattices.

Comment: Do you have an example of nonequivalent higher-dimensional polytopes whose vertex-edge graphs are isomorphic?

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect:  The graph of a simplex of any dimension is a complete graph.  In dimensions >3, it is possible to construct non-simplex polytopes whose graph is complete.  For examples, see Ziegler's book "Lectures on polytopes" (third bullet point on page 10, or more generally, pages 11-16).