# Combinatorally Equivalence between Polyhedra, what does it mean exactly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polyhedra

In Cauchy theorem and also in some Alexandrov theorems I came across the words "If $P,P'$ are Combinatorially Equivalent Polyhedra",i.e those that have "same structure".
Does that mean the following?:

There is a 1-1 and onto correspondece $f:V\to V'$, where $V, V'$ are the vertices of $P,P'$ and $v_1v_2...v_n$ is a face of $P$, if and only if $f(v_1)f(v_2)...f(v_n)$ is a face of $P'$ .

Why just isomorpic graphs of $P,P'$ is not enough here for the polyhedra to have the same structure?

Thanks.

Comment: For convex polyhedra, isomorphism of edge graphs *does* suffice, but this does not hold in higher dimensions - see e.g. [this MSE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199059/) or page 2 of [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/213013185.pdf). I'm not sure whether it is enough for general (possibly nonconvex) polyhedra - off the top of my head, I can't think of any counterexamples.

Comment: Depends what you mean by same structure. Maybe it has something to do with orientation, like the difference between a "right handed" and "left handed" polyhedron.

Comment: @ TheManWhoNeverSleeps,  the book says "the same structure",  verbatim.  I do not think orientation is an issue here. what I am asking more or less,  here is: if 2 polyhedra (of $\Bbb{R^3}$) have isomorphic graphs through $f$,  do their faces correspond through $f$. Thanks.